# Why I get initializer for aggregate is not a compile-time constant warning?

Tags: c

I have such struct

```
struct set
{
    char name[SET_NAME_LENGTH + 1];
    unsigned int input[INPUT_ARR_SIZE];
};

typedef struct set SETA, SETB, SETC, SETD, SETE, SETF;
```

and then I have such a code

```
SETA setA;
SETB setB;
SETC setC;
SETD setD;
SETE setE;
SETF setF;

struct set * p_setA = &setA;
struct set * p_setB = &setB;
struct set * p_setC = &setC;
struct set * p_setD = &setD;
struct set * p_setE = &setE;
struct set * p_setF = &setF;

int main()
{ 
    int resultStatus, r;
    int num_of_sets = 6;
    int i;
    int input_method = NOT_CHOOSEN_INPUT;

    struct set * struct_arr[] = {
        p_setA,
        p_setB,
        p_setC,
        p_setD,
        p_setE,
        p_setF
    };

    memcpy(p_setA->name, SETA_NAME, sizeof(SETA_NAME));
    memcpy(p_setB->name, SETB_NAME, sizeof(SETB_NAME));
    memcpy(p_setC->name, SETC_NAME, sizeof(SETC_NAME));
    memcpy(p_setD->name, SETD_NAME, sizeof(SETD_NAME));
    memcpy(p_setE->name, SETE_NAME, sizeof(SETE_NAME));
    memcpy(p_setF->name, SETF_NAME, sizeof(SETF_NAME));

    for(i = 0; i < num_of_sets; i++)
    {
        printf("\nSET NAME IS : %s\n", struct_arr[i]->name);
    }
...
}
```

But log output not as I expect

```
SET NAME IS : SETA

SET NAME IS : SETA

SET NAME IS : SETA

SET NAME IS : SETA

SET NAME IS : SETA

SET NAME IS : SETA
```

and also warning is

> warning: initializer for aggregate is not a compile-time constant

**WARNING**

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: *Where* do you get the warnings?

Comment: The unexpected output is probably due to a typo: `struct_arr[0]->name` -> `struct_arr[i]->name`. You never showed what `SETA_NAME` etc. are, so there is no way to know for sure. Also what is the point of introducing multiple names for the same type here and for all the redundant declarations of pointers, array of pointers, etc? It is just going to make everything more confusing. Just declare an array of `struct set` directly...

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @walnut yes, fixed. But what about the warning?

Comment: Compiling with C or C++?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Compiler invocation is in image, basically `gcc -ansi -pedantic`, so I guess C89.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko The warning message is relatively clear: If you want to use a non-constant expression in an aggregate initializer, you need to compile against C99 or later instead of ANSI-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `setA` will be put somewhere in memory when the program is executed, but the compiler doesn’t know where. Its address, in `p_setA`, is not a compile-time constant, and can’t be used as an initializer in C. Just use normal assignment instead of initialization.

Comment: It should work in C99 and later though.